# WPF Grid Lines show across childrent element with span > 1

Tags: wpf

Are there any way to make grid to not show over grid children?

I mean, I want grid lines to be visible, but when a children has rowspan or columnspan over 1, I want it to hide the grid lines.

[image]

I tried setting the children (it's a label) opacity to 1 but it didn't work.

Any help will be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not. From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.showgridlines(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1):

> Only dotted lines are available because this property is intended as a design tool to debug layout problems and is not intended for use in production quality code. **If you want lines inside a Grid, style the elements within the Grid to have borders**.